# Is there a way to use getChar() in console and not have it include the tabs?

Tags: c++, windows, getchar

I'm trying to use `getchar()` to read characters one at a time from a windows console. However, when I hit `tab` it visually inserts the spacing of a `tab` in the console, rather than just registering to stdin as `\t`.

I want to hit tab in the console and not have anything change visually in a console, I want be able to have my code interpret tabs separately. 
Is there any way to do this?

I know `_getch()` does this, it doesn't insert a `tab` in the console, but I can't use that function because I need signals to be able to be sent.

Comment: What's the difference between _an actual tab_ and `'\t'`?

Comment: There should be no difference between an actual tab and `'\t'`: https://wandbox.org/permlink/ktEEm6foqe4IIjYy

Comment: @ThomasSablik I mean how the tab is read in the console, there is a difference between ``abb ___ \t`` (___ is the tab) and  ``abb\t``. When I use ``getchar()`` there is  the spacing of a tab that I don't want.

Comment: Please see my link https://wandbox.org/permlink/ktEEm6foqe4IIjYy. I don't understand what you mean. There is no difference.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to visually output to the user, as they type, that they input a tab? So when the user types `abb[tab]` that it appears as `abb\t`? If so, would hitting `[backspace]` need to delete both the backslash and `t`?

Comment: @ThomasSablik I'm not referring to how its read in code, I referring to how its  visually shown in the console.  For example, when you run the node repl, if you hit tab, it doesn't insert a tab like how a text document would.

Comment: You want that something happens after you press tab without enter?

Comment: @OnlineCop Almost, when I  want tab to work similar to how it works in node repl or a linux console, where there is no visual change to hitting tab.

Comment: No, that's not possible because it's unrelated to your program and your code. Most terminals are line buffered. The terminal will send the input to your program after you pressed enter. Before you press enter your program won't know about any input. You need conio.h with `getch` or something similar. You can't achieve this behavior with standard library only.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible because it's unrelated to your program and your code. Most terminals are line buffered (and so are Windows terminal and PowerShell). The terminal will send the input to your program after you pressed enter. Before you press enter your program won't know about any input. You need conio.h with `getch` or something similar. You can't achieve this behavior with standard library only.